# Do I miss something about a remark about topology in this lecture note?

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading a lecture [note](https://www.uni-frankfurt.de/64271720/TopNotes_Spring10.pdf) in topology. There is a remark

> **Remark 1.2.** A quick induction shows that any finite intersection $U_{1} \cap \cdots \cap U_{k}$ of open sets is open. It is important to point out that it is in general **not** true that an arbitrary (infinite) union of open sets would be open, and it is often difficult to decide whether it is so.

I think the part about an arbitrary (infinite) union of open sets is wrong. Do I miss something here?

Comment: By definition, any union of open sets is open. It's for intersections that things could go very false. I think that's what the text intended.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No you don't miss anything here. It is most likely a typo and they mean that an arbitrary infinite intersection of open sets need not be open. For instance, consider
$$\{0\}= \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (-n^{-1},n^{-1}).$$

Answer (score 5):

There's a typo by referring to 'union'. As for intersections, it's not wrong: by induction, you can show that for every $n$, the intersection of $n$ open sets is open, but this is not possible for a non-finite amount of sets. This is consistent with the fact that the 'usual' open sets in $\mathbb R^n$ (with the Euclidean metric) follow this behaviour: for example, $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty B(0,\frac{1}{n}) = \{0\}$ which isn't open.